# What does "fuzzy green meat" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Absolute FreeBSD: The Complete Guide to FreeBSD, 2nd Edition by Michael W. Lucas (2008)](https://www.nostarch.com/abs_bsd2.htm)

Example:

> host.deny This value is used for rlogin and rsh. Avoid it like **fuzzy green meat**.

The author is apparently making a joke, but I don't think I understand it. What exactly is fuzzy green meat?

Comment: It means exactly what it says - would you want to eat [this?](https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-a-packet-of-rotten-salami-meat-on-a-white-background-63376747.jpg)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of saying that seems obvious to native speakers, but can baffle learners of the language. I'm glad ELL is here to help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Meat that has been sitting around long enough to turn green and grow mold "fuzz".

It's meat that you shouldn't even touch, let alone eat.

Answer (score 2):

It's a modification of the phrase [avoid like the plague](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoid_like_the_plague), which means avoiding something bad.